# I can't change my database with ajax and a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new with AJAX and jQuery, so this might be a simple problem. I'd like to update my database by clicking on a button within a browser, using the CodeIgniter framework.

My Javascript looks like this:

```
function endOnboard(){
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8888/users/onboard",
success: function(data) {

  }
});
}
```

My HTML looks button like this:

```
<button onclick="endOnboard();">End</button>
```

And my new php page `onboard.php` like this:

```
<?php

$query_onboard = $this->db->query("UPDATE users SET firstsignup = 42 
WHERE user_id=". $this->user_id);

?>
```

Comment: Is that really the entirety of your *onboard.php* script? That looks like it's been lifted out of a database abstraction class and just plonked into a PHP script...

Comment: Oh man my bad i forgot to tell i'm using codeIgniter as framework

Comment: That possibly makes a bit more sense ... though I've got no idea, never used CodeIgniter :)

Comment: So my code seems good to you then ?

Comment: are you able to get this value `$this->user_id`?

Comment: What you want to do ? I dont understand what is this $this->user_id ? Where u give it?

Comment: I have a propapsal. In your php after run query return query response with json and in javascript ajax success function write console.log(data)

Comment: About the CodeIgniter bit - not a clue, sorry - for all I know it might use a whole world of weird magic methods (Magento certainly does) which would make `$this->db` work outside of an object context, or it might *be* in an object context if that's the action called by the controller at `/users/onboard` - all I can say is that it *looks* wrong. You're not actually sending any kind of GET/POST data through with that Ajax call either.

Comment: Yes i'm able to use $this->user_id it's part of the framework.
I think my problem is when i use ajax